# How can i use firebase cloud storage to handle static files

Tags: python, django, firebase, gcloud, django-staticfiles

I am building a a Practice blog with django, after hosting it on heroku, i discovered that any images i upload using image field or fetch disappear after a while.

Now i started using firebase cloud storage via django-storage gloud backend and it is working fine since then , but when i tried hosting my staticfiles storage from there is get this error

> cross origin request blocked the same-origin policy disallows reading the remote resource at?

how do i fix this?

---

[image]

```py
    if not DEBUG:
    GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jojopage-123-firebase-adminsdk-l8qsw-810f7d7c00.json')
    )

    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
    GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'jojopage-123.appspot.com'

    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

> Here is the error
> [image]

Comment: Where do you get this error? In browser? In Django logs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy i get the error in the browser

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of options:

1. Enable CORS in Django
2. or set up images proxying/routing using web server (such as nginx)
3. or write some Django view which will do images proxying/routing with Python (it's relatively easy, but I'd not recommend it for production use)

The first option is probably the easiest one, you can do it by following a tutorias, for example [this one](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/python/enable_cors_for_django.aspx).

Comment: can i use the nginx with heroku?